# Manipulating arrays to extract unique objects and count occurrences

Tags: javascript, beginner, array, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

The data describes cycling activities (`key1`) and chunks of them (`key2`). In total there are around 1,000 `key1` objects and arrays under `key1` are 1-100 long.

- Is there a simpler, more semantic, faster, or otherwise better way than to use two nested map in step 1?
- I realise that step 3 is longer than it should be and there has to be a better way to do it. How can step 3 be improved?

```js
// Original array
const arr = [
    {key1: [{key2: {id: 1, name: 'a'}}]},
    {key1: [{key2: {id: 2, name: 'b'}}]},
    {key1: [{key2: {id: 2, name: 'b'}}, {key2: {id: 3, name: 'c'}}]}
];
console.log(arr);

// Step 1: Extract meaningful information from original array
const arrOfArrOfObj = arr
    .map(category => category.key1
        .map(subCategory => (
                {
                    id: subCategory.key2.id,
                    name: subCategory.key2.name
                }
            )
        )
    );
console.log(arrOfArrOfObj);

// Step 2: Make the array one dimensional
const arrOfObj = [].concat(...arrOfArrOfObj);
console.log(arrOfObj);

// Step 3: Remove duplicates and count object occurrences.
let dedupedArrWithCount = [];
l = arrOfObj.length;
for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    let objExists = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < dedupedArrWithCount.length; j++) {
        // Two objects are identical if their ids are identical.
        if (arrOfObj[i].id === dedupedArrWithCount[j].id) {
            objExists = true;
            dedupedArrWithCount[j].count += 1;
        }
    }
    if (!objExists) {
        dedupedArrWithCount.push({
            id: arrOfObj[i].id,
            name: arrOfObj[i].name,
            count: 1
        })
    }
}

console.log(dedupedArrWithCount);
```

Comment: what does this data describe? will there always be two levels or might there ever be 3 or more?

Comment: The data describes cycling activities (key1) and chunks of them (key2). In total there are around 1,000 key1 objects and arrays under key1 are 1-100 long.

Comment: so does that mean that there will only ever be two levels of keys?

Comment: Yes that's the case.

Comment: What do you meant by ` cycling activities (key1) and chunks of them (key2).` - Do you mean like 'push bike cycling'? Could you link to the terminology you are using?

Comment: @dwjohnston This is using the Strava API. `key1` is an [_activity_](http://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities) and `key2` is a [_segment_](http://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Segments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Responding to your questions

> *“Is there a simpler, more semantic, faster, or otherwise better way than to use two nested map in step 1?”*

While I like the benefits of functional approaches, they are often slower because of the extra function calls.

Steps 1 and 2 could be simplified by using two [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops (since [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features like `const` are also used). Also, instead of constructing a new object to return in the nested map callback, you can just return `subCategory.key2` (though perhaps you simplified the data and the original data contains more properties that aren't needed in the end).

```
const arrOfObj = [];
for (let category of arr) {
    for (let subCategory of category.key1) {
        arrOfObj.push(subCategory.key2);
    }
}
```

This generally works faster, at least for the small dataset supplied - [see this jsPerf test for comparison](https://jsperf.com/manipulating-data-steps-1-2)

> *“I realise that step 3 is longer than it should be and there has to be a better way to do it. How can step 3 be improved?”*

I was thinking of using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to make an array of counts in step 1 and then use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in step 3 for lookups in constant time, but apparently that was slower, possibly because of the original data set which only has 1 collision. Maybe for a larger dataset that would be faster. [See this jsPerf for a comparison](https://jsperf.com/manipulating-arrays-and-counts).

```js
const arr = [
    {key1: [{key2: {id: 1, name: 'a'}}]},
    {key1: [{key2: {id: 2, name: 'b'}}]},
    {key1: [{key2: {id: 2, name: 'b'}}, {key2: {id: 3, name: 'c'}}]}
];
const counts = {};
for (let category of arr) {
  for (let subCategory of category.key1) {
    const countKey = JSON.stringify(subCategory.key2)
    counts[countKey] = (counts[countKey] || 0) + 1;
  }
}
const dedupedArrWithCount = [];
for (let key in counts) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(key);
  dedupedArrWithCount.push(Object.assign(obj, {
    count: counts[key]
  }));
}
console.log(dedupedArrWithCount);
```

---

### Other feedback

The variable `l` is declared without any keyword:

> ```
> let dedupedArrWithCount = [];
> l = arrOfObj.length;
> ```

Unless this code is wrapped in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), `l` becomes a global variable, which can lead to unintentional consequences if that name is used later. Read more about this topic in [this post about global variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/244085).  It is advisable to use `const` (or `let` if there was a need to re-assign it).

In that same vein, `dedupedArrWithCount` could be declared with the `const` keyword, since it is never re-assigned, just mutated using the push method.

---

One other thing I noticed is that

> ```
> const arrOfObj = [].concat(...arrOfArrOfObj);
> ```

Is equivalent to

```
const flatArr = arrOfArrOfObj.flat();
```

Using `.flat()` appears to run faster in Firefox and Safari but not Chrome, at least when I ran [this jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/js-concat-vs-flat).